# Java not exeucting on a Beagleboard Green @

Tags: java, bash, beagleboard

I am running a new Beagleboard Green Wireless, with the following:
OS: Debian 8.5 jessie
Kernel: armv71 Linux 4.4.9-ti-r25

I downloaded the java zip file:
jdk-8u144-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt.tar.gz
unzipped it, and untarred it and move it to /usr/bin

I set the approripate path and when I attempt to run java -version
I get the following error:
-bash: /usr/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

It seems that this is not the correct version to run on arm or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

ARMv7 (and below) is 32-bit. ARMv8 introduces the 64-bit instruction set.

Judging by the filename `jdk-8u144-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt.tar.gz` it looks like a 64-bit version of Java. You cannot run 64-bit binaries in an arm7 operating system such as yours.

Download the 32-bit distribution of Java.